# How come my "calculate" will not work?

Tags: c#

I need to create a simple c# application to add some quarterly figures.  I am using arrays to "store" the data and then place it in a textbox.

Anyways,  I am having some issues with my calculate section. I have put comment tags around it so you guys can easily find it. The area works, but it requires two clicks and adds it to the line above.  I have been looking at the same few lines for about an hour and can not seem to figure this one out.  Any ideas out there?

```
    //Global
    int lastIndexUsed = -1;
    int[,] quarters = new int[10, 5];
    string[] Branch = new string[10];

    public FrmSales()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void txtBranch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Q1;
        int Q2;
        int Q3;
        int Q4;


        Q1 = int.Parse(txtQ1.Text);
        Q2 = int.Parse(txtQ2.Text);
        Q3 = int.Parse(txtQ3.Text);
        Q4 = int.Parse(txtQ4.Text);

        lastIndexUsed = lastIndexUsed + 1;
        quarters[lastIndexUsed, 0] = Q1;
        quarters[lastIndexUsed, 1] = Q2;
        quarters[lastIndexUsed, 2] = Q3;
        quarters[lastIndexUsed, 3] = Q4;
        Branch[lastIndexUsed] = txtBranch.Text;








        //Display Results

        int ctr;
        int ctr2;
        string outLine;
        string tempName;

        int row;
        int col;
        int accum;


        txtInfo.Text = "";

        outLine =           "  Branch       Q1         Q2         Q3         Q4       Total   " + "\r\n";
        outLine = outLine + "========== ========== ========== ========== ========== ==========" + "\r\n";

        txtInfo.Text = outLine;


        for (ctr = 0; ctr <= lastIndexUsed; ctr++)
        {

            outLine = "";

            tempName = Branch[ctr].PadLeft(10);
            outLine = outLine + tempName + " ";

            for (ctr2 = 0; ctr2 <= 4; ctr2 = ctr2 + 1)

            {


                outLine = outLine + quarters[ctr, ctr2].ToString().PadLeft(10) + " ";

            }

            txtInfo.Text = txtInfo.Text + outLine + "\r\n";


        }

        //Calculate ###########################################################

        for (row = 0; row <= lastIndexUsed; row++)
        {

            accum = 0;


            for (col = 0; col <= 3; col++ )
            {

                accum = accum + quarters[row, col];

            }
            quarters[row, 4] = accum;
        }




        //End Calculate #########################################################

    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBranch.Text = "";
        txtQ1.Text = "";
        txtQ2.Text = "";
        txtQ3.Text = "";
        txtQ4.Text = "";
        txtInfo.Text = "";

    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
```

Comment: How much of that code was necessary  in order to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: I was just wanting the full code up so it could be analysed and people can get a complete understanding.  (maybe an error was made in a different location?)

Comment: I'd go easy with that whitespace.

Comment: What if you do the work to narrow down your problem, then post the narrowed code? You'll get more and better answers, instead of having people like me ignore your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is simple: you use the `quarters` array before you actually calculate the values for it.  Move the "calculate" loop to be above the first loop.

Also (among other things):

- Too many blank lines and whitespace; makes it hard to read
- Don't try to make a formatted report using text; just use a DataGridView or similar
- If you click the button enough times, you will have an array index out of bounds exception, because `lastIndexUsed` will go above 10.

Comment: I agree, some of the details are a bit sketchy, but I am doing it as per the requirements.  At the end I have to add validation so it doesn't error out when entering above 10.  The idea of making a formatted report using a textbox is pretty odd and hard on the eyes. Thanks for your help, solved the problem!